# To get Tx Power of BLE Beacon in Android

Tags: android

What I Know is,

Broadcasting Power (or Transmit Power) is the power with which the beacon broadcasts its signal. The maximum range of the broadcast signal depends on this. 
As I was going through the Kontakt.io blog they says that, Tx power level can be adjusted by the user whose value varies between 0-7(in case of Kontakt beacons & can be different for other beacons). For more info please go through 
[this link](https://support.kontakt.io/hc/en-gb/articles/201621521-Transmission-power-Range-and-RSSI).

The advertising packets sent by beacon contains the information about calibrated Tx Power(RSSI power value at 1 meter).

My question is that,

Is it possible to get broadcasting power , the signal power that beacon sends from the source (as mentioned above the value varies between 0-7) (not the calibrated Tx Power) from BLE APIs?

I had observed that result returned by the toString() method of ScanResult class contains  mTxPowerLevel which is same for different beacons(mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648).

My other question is that, what is this mTxPowerLevel?

If my way of understanding is wrong, please guide to go in a right direction. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

learner,

Using the Kontakt.io Android SDK you can receive this value from range 0-7 (or in case of Beacon Pros  1-7). [Here](https://developer.kontakt.io/android-sdk/3.2.1/quickstart/) you can find the Quickstart guide for the newest right now SDK 3.2.1.

[Here](https://developer.kontakt.io/android-sdk/3.2.1/quickstart/#basic-usage) you can find how to implement simple ranging for the beacons on Android.

Let it be that your beacons broadcast the iBeacon packet, so using iBeacon Listener when you discover the beacon simply use

```
ibeacon.getTxPower()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have gone through the link and are helpful:)